# Proof for the determinant of anti-Hermitian Matrix to be a positive for $4n$ order matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, complex-numbers, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, determinant

I wanted to show that for a anti-Hermitian matrix of order $4n$ with purely imaginary eigenvalues, the determinant of Matrix is real and positive. Here’s what I’ve done:
Let
$v$
be the eigenvector of matrix and
$ \lambda $
be the purely complex eigenvalue.

$$
Mv=\lambda v
$$

Now taking dagger on both sides:

$$
(Mv)^\dagger=(\lambda v)^\dagger
$$

$$
v^\dagger M^\dagger=\lambda^* v^\dagger
$$

Now multiplying by $v$ from the LHS:
$$
vv^\dagger (-M)=\lambda^* v v^\dagger
$$

$$
-M=\lambda^* I
$$
Now taking determinant on both sides:
$$
(-1)^{4n}\det(M)=(\lambda^*)^{4n}\det(I)
$$

Now, as for purely complex number,

$$
(\lambda^*)^{4n}\geq 0
$$

$$
\therefore \det(M)\geq 0
$$

Is this method correct? I needed to show this as part of my Mathematical Physics assignment.

Comment: It is not clear how you went from matrix equality  $$vv^\dagger (-M)=\lambda^* v v^\dagger
$$ to equality $$
-M=\lambda^* I
$$ Don't you find it confusing that you got that every anti-Hermitian matrix is diagonal?

Comment: Yeah @kabenyuk, I must have done something incorrect. But, what is it that I've done wrong? I've no idea.  I used that $$v^\dagger v=I$$. Can you point out?

Comment: Equality 
$$
vv^\dagger=I
$$
is impossible, since $\operatorname{rank}(vv^\dagger)=1$,
but the equality
$$
v^\dagger v=I
$$
is also impossible, since the left-hand side contains a scalar equal to $|v|^2$.

Comment: In general, it seems to me that your statement is incorrect. For example, if
$$
A=\operatorname{diag}(i,i,i,-i), 
$$
then $A$ is anti-Hermitian and $\operatorname{det}(A)=-1$.

Comment: Okay, I got it. Thanks for elaborating! It means that this is impossible to prove.